# How to use database in eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

i am a java beginner. When I am trying to execute bellow icode in eclipse some exceptions are being raised. I've added proper mysql db into eclipse of my application. Can any one suggest how to resolve this problem?

```
package Hello;

import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DbDemo1 {


    public static void main(String[] args )throws Exception {
        Connection con=null;

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String conUrl="jdbc:mysql://loclahost:3306/employee";
         con =DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,"-","-");
        }

        catch(ClassCastException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(con!= null){

            System.out.println("Oracle connection is created");

            }
    }

    }
```

and here I am getting exceptions as follows..

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: the exceptions starts further up. you omitted the interesting part.

Answer (score 0):

the connection url is wrong .. replace "loclahost" with "localhost" .. also, are you sure that your username and password for the DB are like this? if so, you should change them even for testing just to get good practice on securing your DB.